# Is there no ActiveX support for Crystal Reports 2008 anymore?

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports, activex, crystal-reports-2008

We currently use Delphi 2005, and import Crystal Reports 10 ActiveX controls as a Type Library to generate crystal reports.

From what I've gathered, Crystal Reports 2008 no longer supports ActiveX, so even if we upgrade to Delphi 2009/2010, it still won't be able to generate Crystal Reports 2008 reports, is this correct?

That is, there's no way for a Win32 application to generate Crystal 2008 reports. Need to use Delphi Prism, Visual Studio, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robo, unfortunately  [Crystal Reports](http://www.crystalreports.com/) does not include Delphi as one of its supported platforms.
you need to read this articles

["Crystal Reports Support for Delphi – History and Present"](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/index?rid=/library/uuid/70533725-7926-2c10-f3b5-dd99fcfcd482&overridelayout=true).

> **Crystal Reports Visual Component Library for Delphi SDK**
>
> Crystal
> Reports Visual Component Library for
> Delphi was retired in version 11.0 (XI
> Release 1) of Crystal Reports. For
> developers who prefer to use the VCL,
> it is possible to update the VCL
> supplied by SAP BusinessObjects for
> Crystal Reports XI to work with more
> recent versions of Crystal Reports
> such as Crystal Reports XI Release 2
> and Crystal Reports 2008. Please refer
> to the article [Updating the Crystal
> Reports VCL](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/80c191b8-6664-2b10-498e-e1295146891f;jsessionid=%28J2EE3417400%29ID0319414050DB11896652420494829305End). Version 11.0 of the VCL
> can be downloaded from here. **The
> Crystal Reports VCL has not been
> updated since version 11.0 of Crystal
> Reports and thus new functionality in
> latter versions of Crystal Reports may
> not work**. In particular, starting with
> Crystal Reports XI release 2, dynamic
> and cascading parameters will be an
> issue and in Crystal Reports 2008,
> reports using Flash Objects and
> Xcelsius will most certainly fail. For
> more details, see Note 1219099, “VCL
> component does not support prompting
> for dynamic/cascading parameter
> fields” and Note 1323599, “Is it
> possible to use reports created in
> Crystal Reports 2008 in previous
> versions of Crystal Reports?” in our
> Notes database.
>
> **Note: There are no plans to update the VCL.**
>
> ....Technical Support Disclaimer **Delphi
> 2007 (Read as Delphi) is not on the list of supported
> platforms for any version of Crystal
> Reports**. Since Delphi 2007 is not on
> the supported platforms list, no
> issues with the Crystal Reports SDK
> can be escalated for a resolution with
> R&D, unless these are duplicated in a
> supported environment. E.g.; Microsoft
> Visual Studio .NET.

[Thread: Crystal Reports 2008 and Delphi 2007](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=17859)

> Using the trial version of Delphi
> Prism which installed into a Visual
> Studio 2008 shell, on install of our
> Crystal 2008 product it automatically
> updated the shell to include our SDK.
> Everything just works as you expect.
> Please note that Crystal Reports does have to be the last product to be installed.

The best choice you have is to use visual studio integration with Crystal Report.

Bye.